# Will a plugin able to know is_user_logged_in?

Tags: plugin-development

I am currently building a plugin and it doesn't know when a user is logged in.

```
global $current_user;
echo $current_user->ID;
```

It works when embedded on a template but not on a plugin? I have a custom database that depends on user_id, whenever I insert a record, user_id field always has a zero value while others have the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$current_user` global isn't setup until right before the `'init'` action is called.  So any code using it shouldn't be fired until that action or later.

I would also suggest using the `get_current_user_id()` method instead of getting the global directly.

Comment: It diddn't work because it doesn't know whether or not a user is logged in. My plugin hooks a listener into wp_footer when it is page x. Now when I view/load page x in the browser, it knows that a user is logged in, enabling it to know the value of $current_user->ID. But when that page x is called by a service from outside the domain, it doesn't. Is there another way to get user_ID that's suited in my case?

Comment: What do you mean by "a service from outside the domain"

Comment: Like when page x is sent with $_POST thru methods like cURL.

Comment: ...in that case, the page isn't loaded into the browser so $current_user->ID isn't set.

Comment: If you're sending the request through cURL, you won't have a user_id unless you're passing in the COOKIE through the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) to check whether the user is logged in. It will return true or false depending on whether the user is logged in.

Comment: Yah I already tried it. That's how I determined if `$current_user->ID` is set or not. In my plugin I placed a code that checks `is_user_logged_in()` and sends `Is login: yes/no` string to my email add. When page x is sent with http vars, I get the `no` in the string. However, if I embed `echo is_user_logged_in();` into page x's template and load it into the browser, it says I am logged in. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: ...which leads me to think that variables/methods/etc that depend on `session`(not sure) aren't set when the code(hooked somewhere in a page) they are used into is sent/triggered with http post vars.